# How can I make my curl-based URL monitoring service lightweight to run?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, curl, cron

I'm currently building a user panel which will scrape daily information using `curl`. For each URL it will `INSERT` a new row to the database. Every user can add multiple URLs to scrape. For example: the database might contain 1,000 users, and every user might have 5 URLs to scrape on average.

How do I to run the `curl` scraping - by a cron job once a day at a specific time? Will a single dedicated server stand this without lags? Are there any techniques to reduce the server load? And about MySQL databases: with 5,000 new rows a day the database will be huge after a single month.

If you wonder I'm building a statistics service which will show the daily growth of their pages (not talking about traffic), so as i understand i need to insert a new value per user per day.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you storing? Maybe you can replace part of the rows you already have instead of adding all new rows.

Comment: Yea i just edited, its a statistics service which needs to show the daily growth.

Comment: Can´t you just analyze the log files instead of scraping pages? And storing huge amounts of rows with numbers in a database shouldn´t be a problem.

Comment: Well there is no log files because its scraping Facebook pages using the graph ;)

Comment: curl it is then unless there´s a facebook api I don´t know about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I understand that each customer's pages need to be checked at the same time each day to make the growth stats accurate.  But, do all customers need to be checked at the same time?  I would divide my customers into chunks based on their ids.  In this way, you could update each customer at the same time every day, but not have to do them all at once.
2. For the database size problem I would do two things.  First, use partitions to break up the data into manageable pieces.  Second, if the value did not change from one day to the next, I would not insert a new row for the page.  In my processing of the data, I would then extrapolate for presentation the values of the data.  UNLESS all you are storing is small bits of text.  Then, I'm not sure the number of rows is going to be all that big a problem if you use proper indexing and pagination for queries.

Edit:  adding a bit of an example

```
function do_curl($start_index,$stop_index){

    // Do query here to get all pages with ids between start index and stop index

    $query = "select * from db_table where id >= $start_index and id<=$stop_index";

    for($i=$start_index; $i<= $stop_index; $i++;){

         // do curl here
    }

}
```

urls would look roughly like

http://xxx.example.com/do_curl?start_index=1&stop_index=10;
http://xxx.example.com/do_curl?start_index=11&stop_index=20;

The best way to deal with the growing database size is to perhaps write a single cron script that would generate the start_index and stop_index based on the number of pages you need to fetch and how often you intend to run the script.

Comment: This chunks idea sounds great however i never touched chunks before, can you give me some basic example how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

5000 x 365 is only 1.8 million... nothing to worry about for the database.  If you want, you can stuff the data into mongodb (need 64bit OS).  This will allow you to expand and shuffle loads around to multiple machines more easily when you need to.

If you want to run curl non-stop until it is finished from a cron, just "nice" the process so it doesn't use too many system resources.  Otherwise, you can run a script which sleeps a few seconds between each curl pull.  If each scrape takes 2 seconds that would allow you to scrape 43,200 pages per 24 period.  If you slept 4 sec between a 2 second pull that would let you do 14,400 pages per day (5k is 40% of 14.4k, so you should be done in half a day with 4 sec sleep between 2 sec scrape).

This seems very doable on a minimal VPS machine for the first year, at least for the first 6 months. Then, you can think about utilizing more machines.

(edit: also, if you want you can store the binary GZIPPED scraped page source if you're worried about space)

Comment: Thanks! about curl: like Amy said in the 3th answer, the thing is - every page needs to be updated every day at the same time like yesterday so i think i can't really delay each curl with 2 seconds.

Comment: Wait, why can't you delay?  Unless one of the pages has a massive network delay you shouldn't be off by any more time than the previous delay.  If you start at 12:00 noon and it takes 6 hours to complete, the next day you start at noon and end at 6 again.  As long as the pages to scrape are in order each page will be hit at the same time everyday.  If you need to get every page in your DB at one time, then you have a much larger/different problem to deal with.

Comment: Also, store the scrape time with each page source in the DB.  Then run standard deviation per site to see how much time jitter you have.  If it's unacceptable then think of a new strategy.  You won't get it 100% right the first time, but that shouldn't stop you from getting 90% right the first time.

Comment: Thanks, it was a hard decision what answer to chose and even that i didn't chosen yours, just know that you answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use multi curl and properly optimise not simply normalise your database design. If I were to run this cron job, I will try to spend time studying that is it possible to do this in chunks or not? Regarding hardware start with an average configuration, keep monitoring it and increment the hardware, CPU or Memory. Remember, there is no silver bullet.